# Are there more examples of readOnly being used at several levels of a schema to clarify the semantics?

Tags: jsonschema

I've been using the `readOnly` keyword in my schemas and I just realized that I was just making up my own semantics. Now I'm cleaning up a bunch of my designs and trying to validate that I was using this annotation as it was intended. The [validation spec](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.9.4) is what I'm basing this question on but I'd like to be aware of more example usage scenarios.

Let me give three examples. In this first example I mean to say the entire resource is read only. Nothing can be mutated at any level.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "readOnly": true,
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "members": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "member1": { "type" : "string" },
                "member2": { "type" : "string" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think that's too controversial. But originally, my own mental model was that `readOnly` at the top level meant you couldn't replace this resource with a new resource. The server would prevent that. But the internal members were still mutable. So I sprinkled `readOnly` at the `name` sub-schema and each member sub-schema. I think removing all of those was correct. (My mental model was maybe loosely based on how I interpret const variables in JavaScript. If my const var is an object, I can't change the value of the variable, but I can mutate its members or even add members to it.)

In the second example I leave `readOnly` out of the schema completely. So it's not too controversial to take that to mean anything is mutable in the resource.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "members": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "member1": { "type" : "string" },
                "member2": { "type" : "string" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the third example, I want to mix and match

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "readOnly": true
        },
        "members": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "member1": { "type" : "string", "readOnly": true },
                "member2": { "type" : "string", "readOnly": true },
                "member3": { "type" : "string"},
                "member4": { "type" : "string"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example the name, member1 and member2 are immutable. member3 and member4 can be modified.

So the question is, is there anything wrong about my interpretation of `readOnly`?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what you mean by sparse documentation =]

Comment: @Relequestual it perhaps would have better to state that there just isn't as much explanatory supporting text. The core is very well demonstrated via examples in the Understand JSON Schema site: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html  (I keep expecting to find `readOnly` in the index there and always surprised it's not, I presume because its in the validation spec and not the core spec?)

Comment: It doesn't really belong in the core spec document, but I'm not sure we've worked out where it should go, but that isn't the reason. The usage of annotations are broadly undocumented because they are application specific. The exception to this is `format`, but let's not go into that here. Essentially, annotations are keywords which are reserved for application use with specific semantics, but don't actually "do" anything in terms of validation (except sometimes format).

Comment: that's what I figured which is why I said the documentation is sparse (maybe by design?). I wasn't meaning to suggest it was a bad product. that was my way of hinting that perhaps the semantics are up to the application. If so, I understand. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I've revised my statement and removed the comment about sparse documentation.

Comment: Oh, there's no problem or offence taken! I just wanted to understand your comment =]

Comment: If you have any questions which don't fit on Stack Overflow, feel free to join our active JSON Schema slack server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec, as you linked defines the following for `readOnly`...

> If "readOnly" has a value of boolean true, it indicates that the value
> of the instance is managed exclusively by the owning authority, and
> attempts by an application to modify the value of this property are
> expected to be ignored or rejected by that owning authority.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-02#section-9.4

If you take the JSON defined meaning of `value`, it's the bit to the right of the key followed by colon. Therefore I would read this as any part of the value.

The OpenAPI specification only really defines `readOnly` as being applicable to individual properties.

Answer (score 1):

*Answering an already-answered question because I wanted to add a more more detail to the accepted answer, and I have too much to say to fit in a comment*

According to JSON Schema specification, readOnly on parent objects (and arrays) should apply recursively to child properties (and elements)

Here's how you can arrive at this conclusion, starting with the definition linked in the other answer:

> If "readOnly" has a value of boolean true, it indicates that the value
> of the instance is managed exclusively by the owning authority, and
> attempts by an application to modify the value of this property are
> expected to be ignored or rejected by that owning authority.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-02#section-9.4

So, when “readOnly” is defined on any property (including objects/groups and arrays) then it is implied that the property’s value can not be changed. “Change” implies comparing the previous value to the new one. The JSON schema definition for equality check on objects and arrays are as follows

> both are arrays, and have an equal value item-for-item
>
> both are objects, and each property in one has exactly one property
> with a key equal to the other's, and that other property has an equal
> value.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-02#section-4.2.3

In both cases, “equal value” implies that the equality check should be deep/recursive. It is not a shallow equality check.

As such, **JSON schema implies that readOnly is recursive**. If you ever tried to apply a change to a child property/element on a parent object/array which is readOnly, the parent object/array would be seen to have changed, violating the readOnly assertion.